# Why has not my post reopened again

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

My previous post (see this link: [Question about prepositions in English idioms](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47267/question-about-prepositions-in-english-idioms)) has been re-edited again. It is now well-formulated and has been voted "reopened" by three people.

I am wondering why it still remains closed. It has been a couple of days. I am not sure if this meta website is a proper place to ask this question but I'd like to have a try.

Comment: I have reopened it. Tim Osborne's changes made the question clear.

Comment: Thanks @prash !

Comment: Thanks! @prash I was wondering if it is appropriate to ask here but it seemingly is the right place to do. Thanks for your prompt reaction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unsatisfying answer is it just takes time. When a question is nominated for reopening, high-reputation users see it appear in a "review queue", where they can vote if it should be reopened or not. It usually takes five votes to reopen. But that means five different high-rep users need to go through their queues and see it, and this can take several days; we don't have as many people active here as on Stack Overflow or some other sites.

Asking here will draw more attention to it, though.

Comment: In my opinion, the question should not have been closed in the first place. While it may not have been extremely clear in its first version, one could get an idea what was meant, especially if one also read the comments. The asker is also well-known and could have gotten a chance to edit before it was closed. I don't really see the point of a heavy moderator's vote for questions like this that are not pure garbage; it only frustrates the process. I would be in favor of a more lenient approach. (I realize this was not *your* doing, I'm just putting this out here.)

Comment: @Keelan I'd actually recommend making another Meta post about this. This site is relatively small, which means that moderators voting to close is both more important (because it takes longer to get five close votes from regular users) and more dangerous (because it takes longer for people to reopen if they disagree); if we're not striking the right balance there, Meta is the best place to tell us!

Comment: (We've had some Meta questions about it in the past, but I see no harm in another one to raise the issue again.)